# Why does it raise a mutating table error?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am attenting to create a trigger that before delete a row in the table CLUBS check if the column END_DATE is null, if it's null the row instead of deleting the row it replaces the value with sysdate and if is not null the row doesn't get deleted.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRANSFER_DATA 
BEFORE DELETE ON CLUBS
FOR EACH ROW 
  BEGIN
  IF :old.END_DATE IS NULL
  THEN UPDATE CLUBS SET END_DATE = SYSDATE;  
  ELSE
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20033, 'No se puede borrar');
  END IF;
END;
```

I've tried this code but it raises an error:

"table %s.%s is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"

How can I make it work?
By the way, I am working on Oracle sqldeveloper

Comment: Setting `END_DATE = SYSDATE` is quite pointless if the record is deleted afterwards.

Comment: Whether END_DATE is null or not, you don't want to delete the row. So what's the purpose of delete at all? And if you want to delete the row then what's the purpose of updating it anyway?

Comment: Yea but if I use a INSTEAD OF statement I got the error “cannot change NEW values for this trigger type” which I think it means that I am trying to change the value after the value was persisted, so how do I change it to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a view and a `INSTEAD OF` trigger:

```
create or replace view v_CLUBS as
SELECT * FROM CLUBS; -- perhaps add 'WHERE END_DATE IS NULL'

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRANSFER_DATA 
   INSTEAD OF DELETE ON V_CLUBS
   FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  IF :old.END_DATE IS NULL THEN 
     :new.end_date := sysdate;
  ELSE
     RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20033, 'No se puede borrar');
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: I tried before to put a INSTEAD OF statement but i got the following error: 

04084. 00000 -  "cannot change NEW values for this trigger type"
*Cause:    New trigger variables can only be changed in before row
           insert or update triggers.
*Action:   Change the trigger type or remove the variable reference.
So, how can I change it to make it work? Because I can't use a BEFORE trigger on a view

Comment: Then try `UPDATE CLUBS SET END_DATE = SYSDATE WHERE <primary key> = ...`

Answer (score 0):

Processing through a view and an instead of trigger is differently an effective way to go. It seems your prior attempt approached the task incorrectly. A simple view is fully updateble (generally). But in this case you want to intercept the delete and apply the action to the underlying table. Assuming CLUBS is view you process against and CLUBS_TBL is the actual table the trigger you want is:

```
-- create trigger to process deletes on the view
create or replace trigger del_clubs_isd
  instead of delete on clubs
begin 
  update clubs_tbl
     set end_date = sysdate
   where id = :old.id;
end del_clubs_isd;
```

See a full script at [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f692fe6ad34552c7b9a3970f3579d180).  
Further, as presented the user never needs to know the club is not actually deleted, but just marked to appear that way.